# Can ProgressBar be loaded dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

When I use `linearLayout.addView(progressDialog);` Eclipse gives me the error message:

The method addView(View) in the type ViewGroup is not applicable for the arguments (ProgressDialog)

But I watch API and find that

> ProgressBar extends View java.lang.Object
>         android.view.View
>         android.widget.ProgressBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question itself has answer.

> ProgressBar extends View java.lang.Object android.view.View
>   android.widget.ProgressBar

But you are adding `ProgressDialog`, if you will add `ProgressBar`, it will allow you to add as a view.

`Dialog` cannot be added as a view in `Layout`.

Comment: Yes,you are right.   I want to change view of dialog by adding a progressBar when I click a button, it is to change view but not to initialize the dialog,how can I use AlertDialog.Builder? I directly add progressBar to the view(Linearlayout) of dialog,but failed. Can you help me ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the progress bar using progress dialog

`progress=new ProgressDialog(context);
 progress.setMessage("Downloading Music");
 progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
 progress.setIndeterminate(true);
 progress.setProgress(0);
 progress.show();`

for dismissing the progress dialog, call:
`progress.dismiss()`

go through official documentation : [android progress dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)